# Make 2D color histogram with uniform distribution (Likert scale)

Tags: data-visualization, matlab, likert, histogram, scatterplot

**UPDATE:** I've been told that I cannot specifically ask for help in regards to the programming (MatLab and PR Tools), but instead should seek help for general techniques. So that's what I'm doing.

Long story short:
I've created a 2D platforming game where the acceleration and deceleration time for the player avatar change (i.e., how long time it takes before player reaches maximum horizontal velocity). The time values can either be fast [0-240 ms] or slow [241-1500 ms]. The numbers are chosen randomly within these two intervals, so that some players will have [acceleration;deceleration] times like [10 ms;700 ms], [1400 ms;30 ms], [100 ms; 241 ms], etc.

As you can see, the intervals are not of equal size, which means my sampling distribution is uneven, as shown in this figure:

[image: Overall distribution]

My participants rated the feeling of controlling the avatar with these acceleration/deceleration times. They rated how "twitchy", "fluid", "floaty", "responsive", etc. that the game felt. They did this with a 7-point Likert scale (1 = "not at all"; 7 = "a lot").

Here is an example of a scatter plot I made:

[image: Scatter plot of Twitchy and Fluid]

The problem is that it is difficult to look for clusters due to the uneven distribution of the acceleration/deceleration times.

My teacher then suggested:

> Now that I've seen the sampling pattern in Figure 10, I'm less convinced that these scatterplots are useful because it is very hard to interpret whether an increased number of points in the regions < 0.2 seconds is due to the sampling pattern or some real effect.
>
> An alternative would be a 2D color histogram (see [http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~ikarpov/tourney2011/rr/tourney-run-RR-sorted.png](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Eikarpov/tourney2011/rr/tourney-run-RR-sorted.png)) that shows the deviation from the number of a certain rating in each block (e.g. blocks of size 0.24x0.24) compared to the number of ratings you would expect in each block if the probability of each rating was uniform for all samples. In this way, different sampling density would not directly bias the numbers.

I am unsure how to approach this, since I am still relatively new to the world of statistics.

Is this a good approach, or should I do something else? What should the probability be if each rating was uniform? Are there any other methods to reduce the bias created by the sampling density? (maybe using averages?)

The classes are Likert ratings 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7.

(Right now, I use *scatterdui(my_data)* in MatLab with PR Tools to make the scatter plots.)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please be more specific about what kind of help you need.  If it's programming MatLab, then this question is off-topic here; but if you are wondering about some of the statistical or visualization techniques, then they are indeed of interest here but you need to edit this post to indicate that.

Comment: Understood. I've updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you elaborate on what kind of answers you are looking for?  "Approach" is a vague request!

Comment: Have added more direct questions.